# angular send files to server

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to send two type of files in general to server `images` and `zip` I've already installed

```
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.16.0",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.16.0",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
```

I also imported files classes into my component like:

import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(
    // etc.
    private transfer: FileTransfer,
    private file: File
  ) { }

and I'm getting this warning:

[image: one]

## Code

Here is my form in view

```
<form class="ion-padding" [formGroup]="distributorForm" (ngSubmit)="approveDistributor()">
    <ion-row class="ion-padding">
        <ion-col size="12">
            <ion-input type="file" formControlName="coDoc" placeholder="Company documents"></ion-input>
            <small>1- Only <kbd>Zip</kbd> files are allowed. <br> 2- Maximum size: <kbd>10 MB</kbd></small>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col size="12">
            <ion-button class="ion-margin-top" type="submit" expand="full" color="success" [disabled]="!distributorForm.valid">SEND</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</form>
```

Here is my current component function `without files` (This sending data to service.

```
approveDistributor() {
    const distributorForm = this.distributorForm.value;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    this.verifyService.distributorForm(distributorForm.coDoc).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.presentToast('Sent successfully.');
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(error['message']);
      },
      () => {

        this.Mainstorage.ready().then(() => {

          this.Mainstorage.get('token').then(
            data => {
              this.alertService.presentToast('Your data is in process after approve you\'ll be able to work with software.');
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );

        });

      }
    );
  }
```

Here is my service function (This sends data to server)

```
distributorForm(
    coDoc: String
    ) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization : this.token.token_type + " " + this.token.access_token,
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.env.companyDocs,
      {
        coDoc
      }, { headers }
    );
  }
```

## Questions

1. Should I concern about warning I get for FileTransfer? If so how to solve it?
2. How to get my files correct path in order to send them to server?

## Update

I have changed my function to use `formData` like:

```
    const distributorForm = this.distributorForm.value; //my original line

    //added lines
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('coDoc', distributorForm);
    console.log(formData); // this returns empty array under formData in console.

    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    this.verifyService.distributorForm(formData).subscribe(
...
);
```

even with `formData` I cannot send the file to server.

Comment: you are using <input type="file"> this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429122/send-image-from-ionic-to-asp-net-core-web-api/58430492#58430492

Comment: @ShaileshBhokare thanks but my uploaded file is `zip` it is not image so not sure if `base64img` is gonna help

Comment: # Solved I solved my issue and provided the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58907373/8490993).

Answer (score 0):

```
 saveComp() {


            var value: File = file;//get file from input 

            this.customService.saveFile(value)
                .subscribe((data: any) => {
                    // do some stuff

                }, (error: any) => console.log(error))


            return;
           }




saveFile(file: File): any {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
       var url="your url";
       //example url= "http://localhost:9090/"+ 'api/CrmLead/CreateFollowUpByExcel';
        formData.append('FollowUpFile', file, file.name);
        return this._http.post(url, formData, this.requestOptions)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }
  requestOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({

            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,

        })
    };
```

In ApiController C#

```
                var httpRequest = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Form.Files["FollowUpFile"];

                string path = null;
                if (postedFile != null)
                {
                // do some stuff with file                     

                }
```

Comment: hi, your answer had no explanation and i couldn't get anything out of it except using formData and I updated my question based on it. please see the update and if you have anymore idea share it with explanation. thank you

Comment: @mafortis you can use formdata to send file to server as shown above and you can get file to the controller as given the below api controller.  file name should be same in client and server. example "FollowUpFile" in above example. try it you will get solution.

Comment: still not working see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896951/how-to-send-zip-file-in-angular